# easiest way to retrieve all data set from ravendb

Tags: .net, ravendb

I have 350 000 items inside ravendb. With simple `session.Query`

I'm retrieving 128 documents. Is there solution to retrieve all 350 000 documents in one db roundtrip?

Comment: Do you have an estimate on the packet size of that one roundtrip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the streaming API for that.